# CSS Question for Add to Cart

Tags: css

I am using the RWD template. Trying to figure out how to change the color for the add to cart WHEN YOU CLICK ON IT. I was able to find the standard color as well as the hover color, however there seem to be a color when you click on it and I cannot find the CSS to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

`skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css`  line **943**

```
.button:hover, .cart-table .product-cart-actions .button:hover, #co-shipping-method-form .buttons-set .button:hover, .footer .button:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2e8ab8;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```